# is it possible to define custom costmap values?

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo

I want to define custom value for for the costmap.

In costmap2D API there are 4 special values:

static const unsigned char NO_INFORMATION = 255;

static const unsigned char LETHAL_OBSTACLE = 254;

static const unsigned char INSCRIBED_INFLATED_OBSTACLE = 253;

static const unsigned char FREE_SPACE = 0;

How can i define my particular costmap value ?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284877/is-it-possible-to-define-custom-costmap-values-?/) by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2018-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-03-09**:
There's nothing stopping you from saying `const unsigned char FOO=42` but I have the feeling you mean something deeper. What do you want that value to do?

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2018-03-09**:
yes you are right,case is deeper.I want to integrate/use that custom value in the global path planner. Global path planner should create ways on this new defined const unsigned char.The Question is: is it possible and which files should be manipulated?(except costvalues.p, costmap_2d_publisher.cpp )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to do two separate things:

1. You have to get the value into the costmap (if it is not already in the costmap). You could [start here](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20New%20Layer)
2. You have to get the global planner to see the value and act differently because of it. That's a semi-complex operation, but I would [look here](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/kinetic-devel/global_planner/src/astar.cpp#L87) to start.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Developer](https://answers.ros.org/users/31478/developer/) on 2018-03-10**:
Thank you for the valuable answer

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-03-10**:
please hit the checkmark to the left

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2019-03-19**:
Is there a way to do this to create "virtual preferred paths"?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2019-03-19**:
Please open your own question with more context.